# How do i get this queue to work for the palindrome?

Tags: stack, queue, c++98

I resolved my bool issue, but now the output is not printing the whole word front and backwards. only partially.  I posted the output down below. I am pretty stuck on this. I have tried numerous ways of trying to fix it. I know there are some c++ guru's out there that might be willing to lend a hand and tips?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Queue.h"
void print(string s1, string q1)
{
    cout << s1 << "  ";
    cout << q1 << endl;
}
int main()
{
    bool isPalin= true;
    string word;
    //string temp;
    Stack s1;
    Queue q1;
    void print(string, string);

    cout<< " Enter a word you would like to see if it is a palindrome: \n";
    getline(cin, word);

    cout<< "The word you entered is: "<< word<< endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i<(word.size()-1); i++)
    {
        string temp(word, i, 1);
        s1.push(temp);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i<(word.size()-1); i++)
    {
        string temp(word, i,1);

        q1.enqueue(temp);

    }
    while (!s1.empty())
    {
        print(s1.top(), q1.front());

        if( s1.top() != q1.front())
        {
             isPalin = false;
            s1.pop();
            q1.dequeue();
        }
        cout<< " Lets check if this word is a palindrome" << boolalpha<< isPalin<<endl;
    }

Output:

 Enter a word you would like to see if it is a palindrome: 
hello
The word you entered is: hello
l  h
 Lets check if this word is a palindromefalse
l  e
 Lets check if this word is a palindromefalse
e  l
 Lets check if this word is a palindromefalse
h  l
 Lets check if this word is a palindromefalse
Queue created.
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i needed to declare it as a bool. forgot to do that! Now it just isn't printing correctly. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to declare `bool isPalin;` somewhere before using it.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if I get the logic of your program. Shouldn't you initialize isPalin as false and the if palindrome is detected, set it to true?

Answer (score 0):

It is obviously my for loops and my while. I am trying to think of the logic. Stacks are FIFO and Queues are LIFO. but it is starting to confused me on how I would fix this. Maybe I should take one of the for loops away and make it push, enqueue and then dequeue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Queue.h"
void print(string s1, string q1)
{
    cout << s1 << "  ";
    cout << q1 << endl;
}
int main()
{
    bool isPalin= false;
    string word;
    //string temp;
    Stack s1;
    Queue q1;
    void print(string, string);

    cout<< " Enter a word you would like to see if it is a palindrome: \n";
    getline(cin, word);

    cout<< "The word you entered is: "<< word<< endl;
    for ( int i = 0; i<=(word.size()-1); i++)
    {
        string temp(word, i, 1);
        s1.push(temp);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i<=(word.size()-1); i++)
    {
        string temp(word, i, 1);

        q1.enqueue(temp);

    }
    while (!s1.empty())
    {
        print(s1.top(), q1.front());

        if( s1.top() != q1.front())
        {
             isPalin = true;
            s1.pop();
            q1.dequeue();
        }
        cout<< " Lets check if this word is a palindrome" << boolalpha<< isPalin<<endl;
    }


Output: 
 Enter a word you would like to see if it is a palindrome: 
word
The word you entered is: word
d  w
 Lets check if this word is a palindrometrue
r  o
 Lets check if this word is a palindrometrue
o  r
 Lets check if this word is a palindrometrue
w  d
 Lets check if this word is a palindrometrue
```

Comment: please do not post further info as an answer, just edit your question an let people know you did.

Comment: I reposted to show I am still having an error. I see people do this all the time. do I need to repost to another thread for a different question?

Comment: not in stackoverflow. you have to edit your original question, not post an answer. unless of course you find the actual answer on your own, which do happens often.